# How to clip a Oracle query layer directly in a Python script?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, oracle-dbms, mxd, query-layer

I have a query layer directly running from ORACLE database in a MXD. I want to clip this layer  with a layer being created in another MXD in a Python based tool. My question is to do this clip analysis, do I have to make a layer of this query layer locally or I can clip it directly from the query layer? I have success doing it with `MakeFeatureLayer_management` but then creating a layer of 6-7 million records every time this tool runs does not appear efficient and fails the whole purpose of creating query layer. SDE was never implemented for this project and setup was done before I joined the project. 
Alternatively I tried to run the model in query layer MXD but it will work stand alone and results in error with Python.

Comment: also, adding a layer one time won't solve purpose. ORACLE data is continuously being changed by other applications.

Answer (score 0):

Saving it as layer can resolve the issue since layer will take data from data source. so use this saved layer in the model. I need to do some rigorous testing since in my case an app is changing the data in source simultaneously to server side GP model run.